# Get string value of array cell containing a numeric-like value

Tags: javascript, types

I have an array like the following:

```
    var dimensions = [
        ["0.250", "1/4 0.250" ],
        ["0.375", "3/8 0.375" ],
        ["0.500", "1/2 0.500" ]
    ];
```

The first element is specified as a string, but could be interpreted as a number. In some situations I want to treat it as a number, in others like a string:

```
    var string_value = dimensions[ 0 ][ 0 ];
    var numeric_value = dimensions[ 0 ][ 0 ];
```

How do I control which interpretation is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I control which interpretation is used?

You can use explicitly transform them into one by using `String` and `Number` constructors

```
var string_value = String( dimensions[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
var numeric_value = Number( dimensions[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming if it *can* be a valid number, and you want it to be, you can simply use `isNaN` for a conditional parsing.

```
var string_value;
var numeric_value;

if (isNaN(dimensions[0][0])) {
    string_value = dimensions[0][0];
} else {
    numeric_value = parseFloat(dimensions[0][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already a string, just assign and for numer, you could use an unary `+` for casting to `Number`.

```
var string_value = dimensions[0][0];
var numeric_value = +dimensions[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "parseFloat" on the one you want to use as an integer, and leave the other one as is for string (as it's defined within quotes it should read as a string anyway).

Eg:

```
var numberic_value = parseFloat(dimensions[0][0]);
```